# When creating a REST API are there any naming conventions for designating a read only property?

Tags: rest

I was thinking it would be useful if the property name clearly signaled it was readonly.

Take this object as an example:

```
{
    "id":"12154",
    "name":"some name",
    "email":"email@something.com",
    "joinDate":"05/04/2012"
}
```

id and joinDate are of course properties that are readonly and will not allow a change through a PUT/POST request. Is there some type of convention for marking these as such? I was thinking of doing this with underscores:

```
{
    "_id":"12154",
    "name":"some name",
    "email":"email@something.com",
    "_joinDate":"05/04/2012"
}
```

Comment: And what about write-only properties like password. Will you prefix them with $? :D

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure about any REST API convention regarding read-only fields, however, my advice would be to include this information in the documentation. An API without documentation is much less likely to be used.

Comment: Actually there are no property naming conventions at all by REST APIs. There are a few IRI and link building conventions, but that's all. I think the links/forms should describe all the inputs they need to send a successful request, so it has nothing to do with the representation of the properties...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no naming convention for read-only properties in REST. You should, of course, feel free to establish whatever conventions you like for your own API. As Fiver said in his comment, you should make sure they are clearly documented, or your conventions will be some combination of (a) confusing, and (b) noise.

Comment: +1 Exactly, my expectation of a REST API is that the keys returned represent the field names. For example, I would find it confusing if a primary key is represented in one place as `_id` yet I have to use the field `id` to GET the resource using URL parameters.